# Highlight the image Listview with array adapter (Textview And image)

Tags: android

I have listview with array adapter
I try highlight item the  when listview clicked.I have text and image.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/rosybrown"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/saleimage"
        android:src="@drawable/doctor2"/>



    <TextView
        android:text="Jordan Griffin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtdailog" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have highlight the text view by following code:
                      how to hight the imageview when click the listview.
(1)when click the hightlight image view
(2)When click first item another image want add.
when click second another image want add but first item add image must removed.

how to hight the imageview when click the listview.
(1)when click the hightlight image view
(2)When click first item another image want add.
when click second another image want add but first item add image must removed.how to hight the imageview when click the listview.
(1)when click the hightlight image view
(2)When click first item another image want add.
when click second another image want add but first item add image must removed.

Comment: Try adding this `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` to your `ListView`.

Comment: Can you please attach an image of your expected output?